# Coefficeient of $x^k$ in $(1+x)^n$ when $n<0$

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients

I know this is a very basic question. But I simply cannot derive the final answer.
We have the alternate form of binomial theorem if we want to deal with negative exponents. $$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\cdots $$
If $n<0$ the coefficient of $x^k$ is given by $n+k-1 \choose k$. I am trying to derive it from the above series. The coefficient of $x^k$ is $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots (n-(k-1))}{k!}\tag{1}$$
I have no idea or intuition on how to proceed from (1) to $n+k-1 \choose k$ when $n<0$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem:

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{i=1}^n\binom nix^i\implies\;\text{the coefficient is}\;\;\binom nk:=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Comment: When there is a negative exponent we get an infinite series. So even if n is say -3 we can get a coefficient of 100. How to find that coefficient with your formula?

Comment: You use the formula you gave above. What you gave is the general binomial coefficient.

Comment: $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!}$